# Ionic 3 splash screen freezes on some iPhone's

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm building an Ionic app using Angular/Firebase.

I have a problem where *some* iPhone's get stuck on the splash screen. I don't know why, and I'm not sure how to debug. I've tested on 4 iPhone X's, it works on 2, and doesn't work on the other 2. They all have the exact same version of the code. Sometimes I'll add a new version of the app to testflight, and it'll fix the issue, but then a few days later when I update the app again, it breaks, and I don't think it's because of the code. Only some javascript/css changes. This issue doesn't appear on Android.

Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.my.id" version="0.4.9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Example</name>
    <description>my desc.</description>
    <author email="hello@example.com" href="https://example.com">Examepl Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="100" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="handset" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        // the icons/splashscreens
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        // the icons/splashscreens
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.9.77:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.27:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.5:8100" />
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>To connect you to your local university!</string>
    </edit-config>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
        <string>To let you upload images!</string>
    </edit-config>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.11.0">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To connect you to your local university!" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="^2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^4.0.8" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="^1.8.6">
        <variable name="GMS_VERSION" value="16.0.3" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic" spec="^5.1.5">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="0825b6f0" />
        <variable name="CHANNEL_NAME" value="Production" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_METHOD" value="background" />
        <variable name="WARN_DEBUG" value="true" />
        <variable name="UPDATE_API" value="https://api.ionicjs.com" />
        <variable name="MAX_STORE" value="2" />
        <variable name="MIN_BACKGROUND_DURATION" value="30" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.1.1" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="^5.0.4" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.5" />
</widget>
```

and then in my `app.component.ts` file I have:

```
hideSplashAfter6: boolean = true;

this.zone = new NgZone({});

this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    if (user) {
      this.rootPage = HomePage;
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.hideSplashAfter6 = false;
    } else {
      this.rootPage = LoginPage;
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.hideSplashAfter6 = false;
      console.log("Not logged in")
    }
  });
});

setTimeout(() => {
  if(this.hideSplashAfter6) {
    this.splashScreen.hide();
  }
}, 6000)
```

So this removes the splashScreen.

Running `npm outdated` shows what versions I'm on. I don't want to upgrade all of them though as stuff usually breaks when I do that.

[image]

I really don't know what to do. I feel like 1 plugin is causing issues, but I really don't know.. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to debug? There is definitely an error of some sort. Btw also can you explain what is all that timeout code that you have for? Also not sure why you use Zone this way. Maybe share more of the context of your app start cycle

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I'm not sure how I would debug this issue... The timeout is there to "force" the app to hide the app after 6 seconds, since in the config I'm setting the `AutoHideSplashScreen` to false. I'm not sure why I'm doing `Zone` either tbh, it was something I needed at one point, but I'm not sure if I need it there... Any ideas?

Comment: If you have Mac you could try connecting your iOS device using original cable and use safari inspector while navigating your mobile device browser to Mac’s ip address running ionic serve command. But this might not be avail if your app cant run in browser.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I don't have a mac :/ i rely on Ionic Pro. But yeah, the app works great on browser, android, and most iphones.. but sometimes it freezes on the splash screen

Comment: Got it, then i would highly suggest revisit step by step your apps start up cycle and remove anything that is not standard (like the timeout) if you need splash screen to stay longer there are other techniques, also feels like you are using zone in a weird way;(

Comment: try updating at least the `cordova-plugin-ionic` and `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`

Comment: Hi @JaneDoe. Did you found any solution?? I am also facing the same issue.